# HyperLink in flash is not working

Tags: flash, hyperlink

I would like to add HyperLink in my flash banner..

Could you please copy and test this code in html file and tell me why the hyperlink is not working?

```
<a href="http://google.com/"><embed src="http://imperialtrader.com/egfinder/logo/red/moto.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="200"></embed></a>
```

The Problem from my code or from the flash banner designing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the onclick event gets sent to the flash content before it gets sent to the anchor tag. (and then it is lost in flashland)

If you want to fix it, you need some javascript and capture the anchor's onmousedown event from there:

```
<a id="myFlashLink"><embed ... ></a>
<script>
 var anchor = document.getElementById('myFlashLink');
 anchor.onmousedown = function() {
    alert(anchor);
    //insert code here
}
</script>
```